# Is there a software for remote controlling an Sony R1 digital camera with USB?

Tags: camera

Couldn't find one, but I hope that doesn't mean there isn't one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is Linux, you can try gphoto.  Sony R1 is listed as supported.

http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php